# ComboBox SelectedValue Returning an Object And Not The Value

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, combobox, windows-ce

**Goal:** When my form loads I am doing a database call which is returning to me a DataTable that I want to assign as a KeyValuePair(string,string) as the datasource to a combo-box. With the Display Member being the key (RailCarID) and the Value Member being the value (RailcarTransaction_Guid)(I am storing it as a string).

The problem I am having, is when I do combobox.SelectedValue...It is returning to me an object rather than a string. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

I was originally using a dictionary (and it would error out), and thru searching to resolve my issue ended up using a BindingList. Now my combobox on my application displays the object array in the display. Below, is some code snippets:

```
    private void GetAllTransactions()
    {
        BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Transactions = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM RailcarTransaction WHERE IsComplete = 'True' AND IsUploaded = 'False'";
        DataTable transactions = session1.GetRecords(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < transactions.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Transactions.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(transactions.Rows[i]["RailCarID"].ToString(), transactions.Rows[i]["RailcarTransaction_Guid"].ToString()));
        }       
        cboxRailCars.DisplayMember = "Key";
        cboxRailCars.ValueMember = "Value";
        cboxRailCars.DataSource = Transactions;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`ComboBox.ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) could be set to a property of *any* data type (it could be an `int` or `DateTime` for example, not necessarily a `string`), the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property is an object.

You have to know what type you're actually dealing with and convert it back:

```
var selectedRailCar = Convert.ToString(cboxRailCars.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Then may I ask what I am doing wrong in terms of binding the data to the combobox so that only the RailCarID shows - but the GUID value is still around.

Because there is a chance multiple Transactions could take place with the same RailCarID, they'd have to be treated as separate items in my combobox (as each would have a unique transaction guid)

Comment: may i ask what version of visual studio you are using?

Comment: What my combobox is showing - is {[CHOOCHOO, b64e9b71-8543-4cb2-bf4e-c204743b9758]} - and I double checked...nothing else is touching the source.

There is maybe 1 thing worth noting here...the project I am working on is a smartdevice project which operates on a windowsCE enviornment.

Comment: Confirmed - the code is hit. Also confirmed, when I hit the close button on my form, i checked the value just to be sure and the cboxRailCars.ValueMember is = "Value" (same with DisplayMember).

I also did a quick switch to see, got rid of the dictionary (per co-workers suggestion) and just tried to assign them the names of the columns in a DataTable...ignores their existence also. Very strange...wonder if it has something to do with the WindowsCE environment...because if you are confirming this works  on a normal winforms application...thats the only variable remaining.

Comment: After hours of tweaking with this...I figured out the problem. First...this method was part of an "on_change" event in the code...which I didn't realize fired off when I set the Datasource. As you said, but I didn't listen to, the order did matter. I set the Value/Display Members before setting the Data Source...and it works perfectly. Which explains why your stand alone version worked - and mine in the application didn't. Thank you for all your time today!